# How can I iterate over files in a given directory?

Tags: python, iterator, directory

I need to iterate through all `.asm` files inside a given directory and do some actions on them.

How can this be done in a efficient way?

Answer (score 1254, accepted):

Python 3.6 version of the above answer, using [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html) - assuming that you have the directory path as a `str` object in a variable called `directory_in_str`:

```py
import os

directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)
    
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".asm") or filename.endswith(".py"): 
        # print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

Or recursively, using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html):

```py
from pathlib import Path

pathlist = Path(directory_in_str).glob('**/*.asm')
for path in pathlist:
    # because path is object not string
    path_in_str = str(path)   
    # print(path_in_str)
```

- Use [`rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) to replace `glob('**/*.asm')` with `rglob('*.asm')`

  - *This is like calling [`Path.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) with `'**/'` added in front of the given relative pattern:*

```py
from pathlib import Path

pathlist = Path(directory_in_str).rglob('*.asm')
for path in pathlist:
    # because path is object not string
    path_in_str = str(path)
    # print(path_in_str)
```

---

Original answer:

```py
import os

for filename in os.listdir("/path/to/dir/"):
    if filename.endswith(".asm") or filename.endswith(".py"): 
        # print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: This just seems to list the directories or files immediately under a directory. The answer by pedromateo below seems to do a recursive listing.

Comment: Please note that in Python 3.6 directory is expected to be in bytes and then listdir will spit out a list of filenames also in bytes data type so you cannot run endswith directly on it.

This code block should be changed to `directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)
    
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith(".asm") or filename.endswith(".py"): 
            # print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
            continue
        else:
            continue`

Comment: `print(os.path.join(directory, filename))` need to be changed to `print(os.path.join(directory_in_str, filename))` to get it to work in python 3.6

Comment: On the third example, why not just use `.rglob("*.asm")` to check recursively.

Comment: @KimStacks, check docs, it supports both string and bytes, returning value type will depend on it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

Comment: If you're seeing this in 2017 or beyond, os.scandir(dir_str) is now available and much cleaner to use. No need for fsencode. `for entry in os.scandir(path):
      print(entry.path)`

Comment: Prefer `if filename.endswith((".asm", ".py")):` to `if filename.endswith(".asm") or filename.endswith(".py"):`

Comment: @g.o.a.t. where's the answer including an example so I can upvote it? :)

Comment: Note that you may use [`Path.rglob(pattern)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) instead. This is like calling `Path.glob()` with `“**”` added in front of the given pattern.

Comment: In the first solution, are you able to use np.loadtxt ? 
For example:

    for filename in os.listdir('./'):
            if filename.endswith(".hrt"):
                    Sin,Sout,IR =     np.genfromtxt(filename,skip_header=11,usecols=(5,7,9),delimiter='  ', unpack = True)

Comment: Python 3.7+ : remove the line directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str) as was mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729364/python-typeerror-cant-mix-strings-and-bytes-in-path-components

Comment: Is it necessary to put the keyword `code`(continue) inside the if condition?

Comment: Remember to put an `r` before the path string or escape the backslash characters.

Comment: In the second example, use `file` instead of `filename` in the print statement.

Comment: @g.o.a.t. Pycharm tells me entry.path is unrecognized. Any way to let it know the correct type of `entry`?

Comment: Why the `continue`s?

Answer (score 223):

This will iterate over all descendant files, not just the immediate children of the directory:

```
import os

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        #print os.path.join(subdir, file)
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file

        if filepath.endswith(".asm"):
            print (filepath)
```

Comment: A reference for the os.walk function is found at the following: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk

Comment: Handy that this is python2 (and thus jython) compatible

Answer (score 186):

You can try using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module:

```
import glob

for filepath in glob.iglob('my_dir/*.asm'):
    print(filepath)
```

and since Python 3.5 you can search subdirectories as well:

```
glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive=True) # => ['2.txt', 'sub/3.txt']
```

From the docs:

> The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern according to the rules used by the Unix shell, although results are returned in arbitrary order. No tilde expansion is done, but *, ?, and character ranges expressed with [] will be correctly matched.

Comment: For people confused about the ** pattern, this is from the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html : "If recursive is true, the pattern “**” will match any files and zero or more directories, subdirectories and symbolic links to directories."

Answer (score 97):

Since Python 3.5, things are much easier with [os.scandir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) and 2-20x faster ([source](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/)):

```
with os.scandir(path) as it:
    for entry in it:
        if entry.name.endswith(".asm") and entry.is_file():
            print(entry.name, entry.path)
```

> Using scandir() instead of listdir() can significantly increase the
> performance of code that also needs file type or file attribute
> information, because os.DirEntry objects expose this information if
> the operating system provides it when scanning a directory. All
> os.DirEntry methods may perform a system call, but is_dir() and
> is_file() usually only require a system call for symbolic links;
> os.DirEntry.stat() always requires a system call on Unix but only
> requires one for symbolic links on Windows.

Comment: `entry` is a  [posix.DirEntry](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) type with a bunch of handy methods such as `entry.is_dir()`, `is_file()`, `is_symlink()`

Comment: @tejasvi88 otherwise you need to call `scandir.close()` explicitly to close the iterator and free acquired resources

Comment: I got `Expected type 'collections.Iterable', got 'DirEntry[AnyStr]' instead` warning on `for entry in it`.

Answer (score 28):

Python 3.4 and later offer [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) in the standard library. You could do:

```
from pathlib import Path

asm_pths = [pth for pth in Path.cwd().iterdir()
            if pth.suffix == '.asm']
```

Or if you don't like list comprehensions:

```
asm_paths = []
for pth in Path.cwd().iterdir():
    if pth.suffix == '.asm':
        asm_pths.append(pth)
```

`Path` objects can easily be converted to strings.

Answer (score 15):

Here's how I iterate through files in Python:

```
import os

path = 'the/name/of/your/path'

folder = os.fsencode(path)

filenames = []

for file in os.listdir(folder):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith( ('.jpeg', '.png', '.gif') ): # whatever file types you're using...
        filenames.append(filename)

filenames.sort() # now you have the filenames and can do something with them
```

***NONE OF THESE TECHNIQUES GUARANTEE ANY ITERATION ORDERING***

Yup, super unpredictable. Notice that I sort the filenames, which is important if the order of the files matters, i.e. for video frames or time dependent data collection. Be sure to put indices in your filenames though!

Comment: Not always sorted... _im1,im10,im11..., im2..._ Otherwise useful approach. `from pkg_resources import parse_version` and  `filenames.sort(key=parse_version)` did it.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for referring the directory and the list :

```
import glob
import os

#to get the current working directory name
cwd = os.getcwd()
#Load the images from images folder.
for f in glob.glob('images\*.jpg'):   
    dir_name = get_dir_name(f)
    image_file_name = dir_name + '.jpg'
    #To print the file name with path (path will be in string)
    print (image_file_name)
```

To get the list of all directory in array you can use [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) :

```
os.listdir(directory)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite happy with this implementation yet, I wanted to have a custom constructor that does `DirectoryIndex._make(next(os.walk(input_path)))` such that you can just pass the path you want a file listing for. Edits welcome!

```
import collections
import os

DirectoryIndex = collections.namedtuple('DirectoryIndex', ['root', 'dirs', 'files'])

for file_name in DirectoryIndex(*next(os.walk('.'))).files:
    file_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

I really like using the `scandir` directive that is built into the `os` library. Here is a working example:

```
import os

i = 0
with os.scandir('/usr/local/bin') as root_dir:
    for path in root_dir:
        if path.is_file():
            i += 1
            print(f"Full path is: {path} and just the name is: {path.name}")
print(f"{i} files scanned successfully.")
```

Comment: duplicate answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why some answers are complicated. This is how I would do it with Python 2.7. Replace `DIRECTORY_TO_LOOP` with the directory you want to use.

```
import os
DIRECTORY_TO_LOOP = '/var/www/files/'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(DIRECTORY_TO_LOOP, topdown=False):
   for name in files:
      print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: Finally an answer that is not just a copy of other answers but for python 2.7. :)

Answer (score 1):

Get all the .asm files in a directory by doing this.

```
import os

path = "path_to_file"
file_type = '.asm'

for filename in os.listdir(path=path):
    if filename.endswith(file_type):
        print(filename)
        print(f"{path}/{filename}")
        # do something below
```