# Read and do something

Tags: python

How do I loop through a directory?I'm doing this to spit out predictions in tensorflow for poets.It usually takes in only a single file and spits out its prediction.
I'm planning to give it the entire directory,and save predictions in some text file.Im doing this through the docker interface,im thinking of writing a script which will go through all the files in the directory one by one and store the predictions in some text file.

Any help would be appreciated.

.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I iterate over files in a given directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory)

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue while writing a code. 
The following code will recurse through all the files in the folder(including subfolders as well) given by folder_name.

```
import os

with open('prediction.txt','w') as tf_file:
    for dirPath, dirNames, fileNames in os.walk(folder_name):
        for fileName in fileNames:
            results = perform_tensorflow_stuff(fileName)
            tf_file.writelines('\n'.join(results))
```

Hope this helps!