# pd.read_csv not sure how to determine the encoding for my csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, encoding

I am trying to read csv files using pd.read_csv.  I am running into encoding issues and I’m not sure how to proceed.  The first issue I running into is the following error message caused when reading csv fiels that contain a µ character.

“SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xb5' in file GUI_Simpilify.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details”

I’m able to get past this error by manually changing the file name and removing the µ.  However, this is not a solution as I have 1,000’s of csv files to extract data from.

Once I manually remove the µ from a single csv file and rerun my script I get this error message:
“UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 13: invalid start byte”

I believe this is due to the fact that all of my csv files contain both ± and µ characters.
How can I deal with both these errors without manual solutions?

Code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    test_csv = pd.read_csv('OFN 0.1pg_L Split 20-1 (5 fg on column).csv')
```

Comment: Try: pd.read_csv(**u**'OFN 0.1pg_L Split 20-1 (5 fg on column).csv')

Comment: Also, have you considered not typing in names and loop the directory. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory

Comment: Where do the csvs come from? Try to explicitly specify the encoding like this `pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding='utf8')`, instead of `utf8`, you can try `cp1250`, or `cp1252` for windows-like-encoding, or `'latin1` is quite common. Refere here for a more complete list https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: The csv files are exported from a chemical analyzer instrument called a Time of Filght Mass Spectrometer.  Since many of the chemical names contain greek charactrers and ranges for values I'm going to have to deal with characters such as ± and µ.  I can read the file using 'latin-1', but only after manually removing the µ from the file name.

Comment: Initially I did try looping the directory, because I have 1000's of csv files to load data from.  I switched to typing the file names to simplify and limit possible error sources.  Unfortunately, I'm beginning to think I'll have to write a script to change the file names and remove the µ character.  Not the solution I was hoping for, but sometimes you just have to get things done and move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  It's not the most eligant solution, but it works.  I made a method that finds all csv files in the current working directory if any of the filenames contain a "µ" character replace with an "_".  Return a list of all csv file names.  I understand that this could potentially create naming conflicts, but since I'm the end user I'll be careful.

```
    # -*- coding: Latin-1 -*-
    import os
    import pandas as pd

    filenames = os.listdir(path_to_dir)
    filenames_fixed = []
    for filename in filenames:

        if filename.endswith(suffix) and 'µ' in filename:
            new_filename = filename.replace('µ', '_')
            os.rename(os.path.join(path_to_dir, filename), 
                os.path.join(path_to_dir, new_filename))
            filenames_fixed.append(new_filename)

        elif filename.endswith(suffix):
            filenames_fixed.append(filename)

        return filenames_fixed

    csv_list_cwd = find_csv_filenames_remove_nonASCII(os.getcwd())

    for csv_file in csv_list_cwd:
        df_cwd = pd.read_csv(csv_file, encoding="Latin-1")
```

Answer (score 1):

This error because of without specifying encoding.
Add this line at the beginning your python script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: I tried adding the suggested line at the beginning of my code, and it made no difference.  I'm still getting the same error message. "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 13: invalid start byte"

Comment: However, it did solve the first problem.  Python is now ok dealing with file names that contain the µ character.  Before I was getting this error when I had file names containing such characters, "SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xb5' in file GUI_Simpilify.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details".

Comment: Is your file name contains special characters?

Comment: sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')  can you try this one?

Comment: I am using python 3 so I get this error: "AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'"

Comment: Did you reload sys ?

Comment: try this,
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

Comment: I tried that an got this error "NameError: name 'reload' is not defined"