# How can i cat all txt files to terminal using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cat

I want to cat txt files from a folder and cat results should be shown in terminal (Obviously). I have tried using listdir() it but it doesn't work. Required some help!

Comment: Why do you not simply use `cat`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I iterate over files in a given directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory)

Comment: [`listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns a list of filenames. Why did you expect it to print the file contents?

Comment: using cat with each file name is a tough task when I have 50 plus text files. So I wanted to open all and cat results in terminal.

Comment: Please include in your question the code you have tried to use, and please explain in more detail in what way it did "not work".

Comment: You know you can use `cat *.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple implementation uses `glob` to generate absolute paths to files with `.txt` extension, in a loop which reads the file and prints it on standard output:

```
import glob,sys
for filepath in sorted(glob.glob("path/to/directory/*.txt")):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        sys.stdout.write(f.read())
```

using `fileinput` allows to read all the files, and line by line, probably less memory intensive and shorter:

```
import glob,sys,fileinput

for f in fileinput.input(sorted(glob.glob("path/to/directory/*.txt"))):
    sys.stdout.write(f)
```

note that `sorted` is better to ensure that the files are processed in deterministic order (some filesystems don't respect that order)

`sys.stdout.write(f)` still writes line by line, but as suggested by comments you could improve performance and not use so much memory by using `shutil.copyfileobj(f,sys.stdout)`

Comment: thanks for the reply I have one more doubt that what if the files are not in .txt extension but are grep able files. How would it work then?

Comment: Got it for grep we will only use * and trim the extension :) thanks for the help!

Comment: For memory concerns, without worrying about line-by-line behaviors, you can use [`shutil.copyfileobj`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj), replacing `sys.stdout.write(f)` with `shutil.copyfileobj(f, sys.stdout)` (it performs a block by block copy with a fixed size block, so it's not concerned with line endings at all).

Comment: @ShadowRanger excellent suggestion. Just when I thought I wouldn't learn anything by answering that :) well, I know `copyfileobj` just wouldn't have the idea of using it

Answer (score 0):

Just use the command in terminal "cat *"

Or if you want to do it in python:

```
import os
allTextFileContents = os.popen("cat *").read();
print(allTextFileContents);
```

You can also do other things with the contents since its stored as a variable!