# How do I automate this process of capturing detected faces and adding to the database by auto increment assigning ids to every detected face?

Tags: python, sqlite, opencv

I want to add people to database by assigning id auto-incrementing when a face is detected. This is the code to create sql connection and add details.

```
   def insertOrUpdate(id, gender):
        conn=sqlite3.connect("facebase.db")
        cmd="SELECT * FROM people WHERE ID="+str(id)
        cursor=conn.execute(cmd)
        isRecordExist=0
        for row in cursor:
            isRecordExist=1
        if(isRecordExist==1):
            cmd="UPDATE people SET id=' "+str(id)+" ' WHERE id="+str(id)
        else:
            cmd="INSERT INTO people(id,gender) Values("+str(id)+",' "+str(gender)+" ' )"
        conn.execute(cmd)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

So here I am asking the user to enter id and gender.

```
id=raw_input('enter id')
gender=raw_input('enter your gender')
insertOrUpdate(id,gender)
i=0
while True:
    ret, im =cam.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=detector.detectMultiScale(im, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(100, 100), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        i=i+1
        cv2.imwrite("dataSet/face-"+id +'.'+ str(i) + ".jpg", im[y:y+h+30,x-30:x+w+30])
        cv2.rectangle(im,(x-50,y-50),(x+w+50,y+h+50),(225,0,0),2)
        cv2.imshow('im',im[y-30:y+h+30,x-30:x+w+30])
```

How do I automate this process of capturing detected faces and adding to the database by auto increment assigning ids to every face ?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).