# unindent does not match any outer indentation level. When I about to tokenize the string

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I opened a folder in that many file and I want to parse every file and and pre process it and write tokens into the same current files which they belong to. Please help me with that.
[image]

Comment: try to clear all the white space around the problematic code snippet or below and above it a few rows, there is some hidden character somewhere I guess.

Comment: Refer to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code probably has whitespaces and tabs mixed with each other.

One way to solve this would be replacing all spaces with tabs or vice versa.

But as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/10611983/tomothy32 PEP8 recommends spaces so use spaces.

Try this and it should work.

Comment: [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) recommends spaces, not tabs.