# How do I solve this error in Python . There are multiple files in a folder and i need to create folders based on the file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, python-requests

Please help me out with this code as I am a beginner in python struggling .
There needs to be one xyz file for every data file.The output format should be as follows :
[ID]> [Year]>[Year-Month]>[Sub-ID]>[xyz.txt]
The station ID for data is IN-023C
Year to be determined based on the timestamp of the file
Year-Month needs to be determined based on the timestamp of the file
Substation-ID depends on the substation read (if in file I1 then it should be placed in folder Ipl1 if I2 then folder IPL2)xyz.txt has the same name as the file.txt
same file name :[IN-023C]-I1-2018-12-01.txt
code I have written :

```
import os 
from shutil import copyfile
         folder_path = '*C:\Users\P&K\Desktop\Assign\*'
         os.chdir(folder_path)
         for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
          stationid = file[1:9]
          year = file[14:17]
          month = file[14:20]
          substation = file[11:12]
          if file == 'I1':
          print ('Inverter1')
          break
          else:
          print('Inverter2')
          final_path = folder_path + '/' + stationid + '>' + year + '>'+'month'+'>'+'substation'+ '/' + 
          file + .txt'
          copyfile(file, final_path)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I iterate over files in a given directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Python+Iterate+file+directory

Comment: take a look at this site[ https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp ]

Comment: So , the code which I wrote is a wrong way - to get the year and month from the file, how do I do that