# Define a Python function to rename files passing names and path as arguments

Tags: python, function, file-rename

I would like to create a python function where I pass as arguments the **name** and the directory **path** of some files which I want to rename; something like `def my_fun (name, path):`  The directory path is the same for each file. I did it in this way but I cannot turn it into a function form as I look for.

```
path = input("tap the complete path where files are")
for name in files_names:
    name = input("insert file name as name.ext")
    old_name = os.path.join(path, files_names)
    new_name = os.path.join(path, name)
    os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

Comment: This answer will help you with iterating through the files in the directory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10378012/9215267

Comment: Thank you Siddharth!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to pass in the path and file name *(a list of names)* as arguments:

```
def rn(path, files_names):
    new_name = input("Input the new name: ")
    for i,name in enumerate(files_names):
        old_name = os.path.join(path, name)
        new_name = os.path.join(path, f"{new_name.split('.')[0]}{i}.{new_name.split('.')[1]}")
        os.rename(old_name, new_name)

path = input("tap the complete path where files are")
file_names = ['image.png','car.png','image1.png','photo.png','cake.png']
rn(path, file_names)
```

This will rename all the files in the list with what the user input into `new_name`, labeled starting from `0`.

Comment: Should it be feasible to pass the new_name inputs as parameters instead of files_names, which corresponds basically to old_name?