# How to convert 100's of .log files to .xlsx files

Tags: python, pandas

This a a portion of a larger code.

I have a directory with 100's of .log files that I need to  convert to .xlsx files one at a time. I wrote this code;

```
import csv
import glob
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.log', delimiter=r"\s+", header=None, names=list(range(20)))
df.to_excel('input.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
```

Which works for a single file. What do I need to add to have it look through the directory and convert each file regardless of how many there are?

Comment: Is there a systematic how the files are named?

Comment: I think you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory) useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob("*.log")

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=r"\s+", header=None, names=list(range(20)))
    df.to_excel(file+'.xlsx', index=Flase)
```

Comment: the files are named with the directory /2020*****.log