# Copying files with a specific name to another folder

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I have folder with 1500 txt files and also folder with 20000 jpg files. 1500 of jpg files are named the same as txt files. I need that these jpg files with names similar to txt files to be moved to another folder.
To put it simply, I have txt files from 1(1) to 5(500), I need to move only files with the name from 1(1) to 5(500) from the folder with jpg files from 0(1) to 9(500).
I tried to write a program in Python via shutil, but I don't understand how to enter all 1500 valuse, so that only these files are moved.
Please tell me how to do this? Thanks in advance!
I found all the names of txt files and tried to copy pictures from another folder with the same names.
Example on pictures:
I have this names
[image: I have this names]
I need to copy only this images, because their names are the same as the names of txt:
[image: I need to copy only this images, because their names are the same as the names of txt]

```
import os
import glob
import shutil


source_txt = 'C:\obj\TXT'
dir = 'C:\obj\Fixed_cars'
vendors =['C:\obj\car']

files_txt = [os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in os.listdir(source_txt)]

for file in vendors:
     for f in (glob.glob(file)):
         if files_txt in f: # if apple in name, move to new apple dir
             shutil.move(f, dir)
```

Comment: Please show us what you've written already, and explain further what part of that code doesn't do what you want it to do. Also, please give us some examples of file-names that should / should not be matched / copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using [this answer on looping through files of a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10378012/12663901)
you can loop through the files of your folder.

```
import os

directory = ('your_path_in_string')
txt_files = []
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"): 
         txt_files.append(filename.rstrip('.txt'))
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if (filename.endswith(".jpg") and (filename.rstrip('.jpg') in txt_files)): 
         os.rename(f"path/to/current/{filename}", f"path/to/new/destination/for/{filename}")
```

[for the the moving file part you can read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858026/12663901)