# Is there any python program to save 'n' videos in 'n' folders with the name of the video all at once instead of creating each folder for each video?

Tags: python, video, directory

> I have 100 videos extracted in the form of .MP4, and I have to save each video in each New Folder respectively with the folder name as the video name itself but without .MP4 extension.

> Finally I'll get 100 videos saved in 100 folders. This is a very time consuming process if I do manually by creating a folder and cut/copy the 1st out of 100 videos and paste it in the New Folder and then rename the folder with the video name. Similarly for 100 videos.

> So, is there any Python program to do it very quickly and automatically through some code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question does not meet the guidelines of Stackoverflow, as this is not a programming question but rather general and more a request for a software recommendation. 
This can definitly be done with Python, with a little bit of learning. If you are interested in programming it yourself, I can post you a few starting points

Comment: Yes please, I am interested in programming it myself. Any resources or important points that you have, please share it. Thank you!

Comment: I added an answer with links that should point you in the right direction. CHeers

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I'll go through all the links and learn the concepts.

Comment: Great. If you need anything you can get back to me or the great community in general

Answer (score 0):

Here are links to all the subproblems, I think you will encounter:

1. Find and list all files in a directory (all your videos) [Files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)
2. Create a directory with Python (create your subfolders) [Create Folder](https://thispointer.com/how-to-create-a-directory-in-python/#:%7E:text=Python%27s%20OS%20module%20provides%20an%20another%20function%20to%20create%20a%20directories%20i.e.&text=.makedirs(path)-,os.,mkdir%20%2Dp%20command%20in%20linux.)
3. Move a file to another folder (move the videos) [Move files](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-move-file/)
4. Iterate over files in directory (your movies) [Iterate through files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory)

**COMMENT:**

I do know, that just posting links is not an appreciated way of answering questions on SO, however, the question is asked rather general with no prior programming experience. I therefore don't want to discourage the attempt to start programming, and provide some guidance this way.