# How to deal with dataset containing multiple csv files?

Tags: python, lstm, tf.keras

I'm implementig an LSTM but i have problem of dataset.
My dataset is in the form of multiple CSV files(different problem instances) I have more than 100 CSV files in a directory that I want to read and load them in python. My question is how I should proceed to build a dataset for training and testing. Is there a way to split each csv file into two parts (80% training and 20% testing) then grouping the 80% of each as data for training and grouping the 20% for testing.
or is there another more efficient way of doing things
How do i take these multiple CSVs as input to train and tet the LSTM?
this is a part of my csv file structure [CSV file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMhbN.png)
and this one a screen of my csvs files (problems instances)[csvs files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTcCk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas `pd.concat()` to combine multiple dataframes with the same columns ([pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)).

You can [iterate through that directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory) to create a list of csv file names, read each csv using `pd.read_csv()`, and then concatenate into a final dataframe with something like this:

```
final_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=[<YOUR COLUMNS>])
for csv_path in csv_files_list:
    df=pd.read_csv(csv_path)
    final_df=pd.concat(final_df, df)
```

From here, you can split your training and test data using sklearn or whatever other method you like.