# Python - How can I iterate through folders and subfolders?

Tags: python, iteration

I would like to iterate through the folders 1,2,3,4,5... etc. (which contain data themselves). I don't want to go into the that folder since all the information I need is in the folder name. Folders 2019 and 2020 are structured the same as 2018, but the names of the folders with numbers are unique.

How can this be done most efficiently?
[image: Current Architecture]

Comment: Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory

Comment: Welcome @Niek, what helps is that 'what have you done'.. to make it more answerable