# Loop through PDFs in a folder and send them to an Endpoint using Python

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, salesforce, endpoint

I would like to know whether or not it is possible to loop through a folder filled with PDFs to an endpoint based on Salesforce using Python.

Dataset = a number of PDF files in one folder

Action required:

- Link with the endpoint on Salesforce & authenticate with the endpoint
- Loop through & Send all of the PDFs 1 by 1 in the folder to the endpoint which will parse these PDFs

Answer (score 0):

For Salesforce you can use a library such as this one: https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/

To loop through files in a folder you can look at these answers:
[How can I iterate over files in a given directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory)