# Need to use python to convert media files to mp3 files

Tags: python-3.x

```
import moviepy.editor as m
import os
for i in os.listdir():
    if i == ".mpeg": #How do I make that work(I know it can't, I just have it there to explain what I need)
        video = m.VideoFileClip(i)
        video.audio.write_audiofile(i)
```

Need it to sort through files, find the media ones, and change them to .mp3

Comment: Please use [edit] to explain your question (and create a better title)   (Info on how to format your question is here: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) )

Comment: Are you trying to extract audio from `.mpeg` files, and output as `.mp3` files?

Comment: Yes. In goes media, out goes mp3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I iterate over files in a given directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory)

Comment: You should have kept those back-quotes in your question. It is formatting the code.... (I re-applied my edit)

Comment: But is the problem getting the audio, or only applying it to the files that are actually `.mpeg`? For instance, your if-statement could filter correct files like this: `if i.endswith(".mpeg"):`. Is that your problem? Filtering files?

Comment: Nope. It still doesn't work for some reason. It still doesn't throw an error though.

Comment: You are also overwriting the .mpeg with the audio (but with same filename).

Comment: That is my problem. I looked at the iterate link and also using the stuff I know and it doesn't work. Still doesn't throw an error though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Comment: Now it says that ffmpeg is screwed up. Anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific. Try and search for your specific error/stacktrace. If you can't find a question that solves it, then open a new question and be very specific about your input, expected output and the error you get.

Comment: Ok anyone know why when I install or upgrade FFMPEG and then do version it says -bash: FFMPEG: command not found, but when I install or upgrade it says Requirement already satisfied: FFMPEG in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.4)?

Comment: No, not here - create a completely new question. But search for an existing one first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would change your code. Extract the filename and extension, use the extension to filter files and use the filename to create a new filename with the `.mp3` extension. This makes sure you don't overwrite your source video file with audio.

```
import moviepy.editor as m
import os
for file_path in os.listdir():
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
    if file_extension == ".mpeg":
        video = m.VideoFileClip(file_path)
        audio_file_path = filename + ".mp3"
        video.audio.write_audiofile(audio_file_path)
```

Comment: I want to overwrite the file though.

Comment: Then you can delete the .mpeg afterwards, probably with `os.remove(file_path)`.