# How can I open a folder with argparse

Tags: python, arguments, argparse, python-zipfile

I want to open a folder containing x zipfiles.

I have this code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test')
parser.add_argument("foldername", help="Foldername of log files archive to parse")
args = parser.parse_args()
with open(args.foldername) as files:
    filename = args.filename
    print(filename)
```

But I get error code:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Test'

I would like the zipfiles in the folder to be listed in an array when I run the code.

Comment: You don't have the permission to read the file. Further, if it is a folder, you have to use `os.listdir(args.foldername)` to get all files, then iterate through the list for reading by `os.path.join(args.foldername, filename)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting a permission error, but using `open` on a directory won't do what you want. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for Python's `open` requires that its input is a string to a *file*, not a *directory*.

If you want the files in a directory given the name of the directory as a string, refer to [How can I iterate over files in a given directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get an array with the zip files inside the folder. However, I now get a new error. I run a for loop.                                             
for files in range(len(filename)):                                              
       archive = zipfile.ZipFile(filename[files], 'r')                I get new error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.zip'.                                            Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have permission to read those files? Test, whatever file or folder it is, doesn't seem to be readable from your script.