# accessing files within directories via with open

Tags: python

the code gives error when I try to open directory as I want it to open the files within the directories however I am getting below error.

```
    with open(i, 'rb') as f:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'hard_signatures'
```

```
    for i in SHA256_HASHES_pack1:
            with open(i, 'rb') as f:
                md5 = hashlib.md5()
                sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
                while True:
                    data = f.read(BUF_SIZE)
                    md5.update(data)
                    sha1.update(data)
                    if not data:
```

Comment: Could you post the text in SHA256_HASHES_pack1?

Answer (score 1):

That `open` function opens a `file`, not a `directory`. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_open.asp

If you want to cycle through all files in directory `i` see [How can I iterate over files in a given directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory)