# Running code to multiple files in one folder

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I wrote a code that starts with

```
import pandas as pd
# Code starts by reading one txt file
df=pd.read_fwf(r'C:\Users\youngrakchoi\Desktop\.filename.txt',sep='')

#-------My code--------#

# Code ends with saving the results
VOLTAGE_fin.to_excel(r'C:\Users\youngrakchoi\Desktop\NAME.xlsx')
```

Now I would like to run this code to all files saved in specific directory(folder) and save the file as the original file name (eg. save VOLTAGE_fin as 'filename').

Could anybody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: list the files from the folder using glob and iterate over them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory

Comment: Your question is slightly *unclear*. Are you asking how to use the variable name as the name of file being saved? If that's the case, you can use string formatting.

Comment: @vyi I am trying to apply my coding to multiple files in one folder and at the end I would like to save my results into a original file name(say if I call 1.txt 2.txt ... and my results should be saved as 1.xlsx 2.xlsx ...)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will do the job.

```
my_var_name = [ k for k,v in locals().items() if v == VOLTAGE_fin][0]
VOLTAGE_fin.to_excel(f"C:\\Users\\youngrakchoi\\Desktop\\{my_var_name}.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to apply my coding to multiple files in one folder

You can read the files (their names) in a given directory with the `listdir` function from `os` module. A minimal example follows:

```py
import os
path = 'C:\\Users\\youngrakchoi\\Desktop\\my_dir\\'
all_files = os.listdir(path)
for file_name in all_files:
    ## Do your work 
    ## Finally save your output in xlsx format as follows
    pd.to_excel("{}/{}.xlsx".format(path, file_name))
```