# export part of CSV file to a new CSV file with Python

Tags: python, export-csv

i need to export specific column from csv to new csv, but i couldn't get proper result.plase support to chcek

Id  Name    Course  City    Session

21  Mark    Python  London  Morning

22  John    Python  Tokyo   Evening

32  Shaun   Java    Tokyo   Morning

```
import csv
with open(r'D:\Clouds\OneDrive\Desktop\python_tamrin\students.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(read_obj)
    with open ('new_nemes_1.csv','w', newline='') as new_file:
        csv_writer=csv.writer(new_file)
        for line in csv_reader:
            c_1 =row['Id']
            csv_writer.writerow('c_1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line` (or `row`) is a `list`, it doesn't have `Id` key. You need to write a slice of that list to the new file

```
...
for row in csv_reader:
    csv_writer.writerow(row[:1])
```

Comment: thanks alot, it worked , if i want to have specific Id from row[:1], for example 22, how i should modify ?

Comment: @nasrin add a condition to the `for`, `if row[0] == '22':`

Comment: if i have multiple CSV files with same data structure in one folder , how i can loop this activity to get the data of all CSVs of that folder? sorry for many questions,

Comment: @nasrin something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory

Comment: @nasrin If you have a new question you should post a new question, it's difficult to answer in the comments.

Comment: thank u and i will make new post in such these cases in future